# allow photo/video in comments

Tags: plugins, comments

I have a request to allow subscribers to upload/embed photos or video in comments. Is anyone aware of an existing plugin to handle this, I couldn't find anything suitable. I found examples of code to change the tags that are stripped from comments which would allow embedding, but I'm not sure that really fits the bill and would require change to a core file.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently looking for the same thing (only for photos), and the target audience isn't likely to use photo sharing services, so I opted for a paid plugin from [codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/comment-image-upload-images-with-comments/112119). This was the best thing I could find and pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks, that's the plugin I ended up going with. The client dropped the video upload requirement.

Comment: Great, I haven't had any problems with it, although I think my project is getting cancelled!

Answer (score 0):

You could use oEmbed - allowing users to embed photos and videos from popular sites such as Flickr, Vimeo and YouTube simply by writing in the URL of the media they wish to embed.

A plugin that enables oEmbed for comments can be found in the WordPress Plugin Repository at:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oembed-for-comments/

Comment: Thanks yes, that plugin pretty much does what code I found would do, but without changing core files. The client really wants the facility to allow uploads directly though, despite my urging contrary

Answer (score -1):

You could use plugins to insert image or video with and as a comment.

Here are some links:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-images/

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-comment-images

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/riffly

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contus-video-comments/

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imagements

wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-toolbar

Hope these links help you little bit. All the best ;)